# Can I say that the source code is "saturated" with irrelevant expressions?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I'm looking for a word that would mean "filled with so much gibberish that it's hard to extract what's relevant", "such is that the important bits are obscured by irrelevant ones". The word that comes to mind is "saturated", but I am not sure if that's the one.

Examples:

- These stats are severely *saturated* with responses posted by bots.
- We're only reporting newly introduced issues so that reports are not *saturated* with what we already know.
- Adding these function calls all over your code will *saturate* your actual logic.

Comment: Yes, you can say that. Or it is *dense* with such things. Or say that the *signal to noise ratio is low*. Or say that the code contains a lot of *cruft*. Or just say that it is *overly verbose* or *noisy*.

Comment: I would use "riddled' for some of your cases.  The sense you're looking for in your last example is unclear, however.

Comment: As used in the question itself, _obscured_ should suffice.

Comment: ***Saturated*** has at its base a meaning of unable to absorb any more.  I would not advise using the word in your context and I certainly would not use it with qualifiers such as severely. @HotLicks’s ***riddled*** seems apropos to me.

Comment: @HotLicks the ~exact sentence I wanted to use this in is: «But alas, this is not a short piece of code, and sprinkling these bad boys [aforementioned long method calls] all over your Activities will heavily saturate your logic.» But I think I'll rephrase it with _clutter_ or _obscure_. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use saturated like that (referring to your title), but cluttered is shorter.

1. Your code is cluttered.
2. Your code is cluttered with irrelevant expressions.

Sentence (1) conveys your description. Sentence (2) conveys your title and description.

Cluttered (OED)

> To crowd (a place or space) with a disorderly assemblage of things. Usu. in pass. Freq. const. up.

Saturate (OED)

> 6. intr. To reach or exhibit a condition of saturation, in any sense; to reach a state in which no further change or increase is possible.

Note saturate alone has no negative connotations, and you cannot say severely saturated.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say the code is *rife* with irrelevant noise.  From www.vocabulary.com:

> [***rife***](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rife) - Use the adjective rife to mean "full of" or "widespread," especially when you're talking about something negative.

Your meaning with *saturated* is clear to me, but it would mean that it was impossible to add more irrelevant junk.   And that's not the case with code.

Comment: I’ve edited in the required citation credit for you. Our reuse terms allow the content to be used in alternate formats in which the hypertext link would be lost, such as a printed page. The credit would then be irrecoverable, so we ask that any text that is not your own be duly credited in plain text not just in code alone. See [How to Reference Work by Others](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) in our help center for more information about this.

Comment: I have never heard this word before, which makes me believe it's not a very common one (especially to use in a tech article aimed at readers worldwide). But thanks for suggestion anyway!

Comment: @Actine - [it is used half as often as the term *source code*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rife%2Csource+code&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csource%20code%3B%2Cc0).  It is not a particularly uncommon or archaic word.